# Create one JSON from another, with extra data va JQ

Tags: json, jq

I have this file:

```
[
    "smoke-tests",
    "push-apps-manager"
]
```

I'd like to get this output using JQ:

```
{
  "errands": [
    {"name": "smoke-tests", "post_deploy": true},
    {"name": "push-apps-manager", "post_deploy": true}
  ]
}
```

It seems so simple, yet, I have so much difficulty here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little tricky, since you need to embed the input into the list bound to the `errands` key. Start by creating the sequence of `name`/`post_deploy` objects:

```
% jq '.[] | {name: ., post_deploy: true}' names.json
{
  "name": "smoke-tests",
  "post_deploy": true
}
{
  "name": "push-apps-manager",
  "post_deploy": true
}
```

Then wrap that in the list in the outer object:

```
% jq '{errands: [.[] | {name: ., post_deploy: true}]}' names.json
{
  "errands": [
    {
      "name": "smoke-tests",
      "post_deploy": true
    },
    {
      "name": "push-apps-manager",
      "post_deploy": true
    }
  ]
}
```

You can also use the `map` function (which I rarely remember how to use correctly, but it turns out is pretty simple here):

```
% jq '{errands: map({name:., post_deploy: true})}' names.json
```

Comment: 100% awesome! now, which method to use???? honestly, i like the map method, i'll go with that.

Comment: Probably `map`; to be honest, taking a closer look at the man page, I unknowingly reimplemented `map` with my first solution. (`map` is *defined* as `[.[] | x]`.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach.  If you are new to **jq** it may be easiest to work towards the goal in small steps.

1) Start with the identity filter

```
 .
```

which produces as expected

```
[
  "smoke-tests",
  "push-apps-manager"
]
```

2) next add the outer object with the `"errands"` key:

```
{ "errands": . }
```

which produces

```
{
  "errands": [
    "smoke-tests",
    "push-apps-manager"
  ]
}
```

3) next move the data into an array

```
{ "errands": [ . ] }
```

which produces

```
{
  "errands": [
    [
      "smoke-tests",
      "push-apps-manager"
    ]
  ]
}
```

4) add the inner object with the `"name"` and `"post_deploy"` keys

```
{ "errands": [ { "name": ., "post_deploy": true } ] }
```

which produces

```
{
  "errands": [
    {
      "name": [
        "smoke-tests",
        "push-apps-manager"
      ],
      "post_deploy": true
    }
  ]
}
```

5) Now we're really close.  All we need to do is take advantage of **jq**'s [Object Construction behavior when an expression produces multiple results](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#ObjectConstruction:%7B%7D) :

```
{ "errands": [ { "name": .[], "post_deploy": true } ] }
```

which gives us the desired result

```
{
  "errands": [
    {
      "name": "smoke-tests",
      "post_deploy": true
    },
    {
      "name": "push-apps-manager",
      "post_deploy": true
    }
  ]
}
```